# Changing Publication Settings through the Core Service

Tags: core-service, workflow, 2013-sp1-hr1

Am I missing it or is there nothing in the API to allow us to access the Workflow (and Translation) settings tab in a Publication through the Core Service?

I basically want to set the *Enable Workflow Process Associations in Shared Schemas and Structure Groups* on the **Workflow** Tab to checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LinqPad and CoreService we can easily access the ShareProcessAssociations value thus:

```
var allPubs = Tridion.Publications;

foreach (var pub in allPubs)
{
    var pubData = (PublicationData) Tridion.Read(pub.Id, new ReadOptions());
    string pubName = pub.Title + " [" + pub.Id + "]";
    string wflow = "WFLOW = N";

    if(pubData.ShareProcessAssociations == true){
        wflow = "WFLOW = Y";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(wflow + "\t" + pubName);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Translation settings tab is most likely app data, workflow might be the same. So to change these settings you'd have to change the app data on that Publication, but you'd have to figure out what format it is exactly in (it is XML, but what elements etc.) and under which application ID it sits.

See App data tm:Rights (as an example)

Comment: I'd figured as much Bart - meaning not really _supported_ to mess with the XML. I've reached out to support to with our suggestion to see what they come back with. Thanks again.

I'll confirm they are App Data and mark as the answer when/if that's the case.

Comment: App data with the application ID tm:Rights :(

Answer (score 3):

As far as workflow inheritance, that's a property on the Publication object. you can translate my PowerShell to something meaningful to you... :)

```
$tridionPub = Get-TridionPublication -Name $PublicationName -AllPublications $AllPublications
#$Inherit is param, either $true or $false
$tridionPub.ShareProcessAssociations = $Inherit
Update-TridionItem -Item $tridionPub
```

Comment: Interesting - I can set it in the scope of writing the value out but I can't find any way to save / commit the change back into the CM.

Comment: core service has Update method. for me, it's like this:
$client = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient
$client.Update($Item, (New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ReadOptions))